# Webassembly wrap instruction: Meaning of i % 2^32

Tags: java, webassembly

I am writing a Webassembly runtime in Java. One instruction is the `i32.wrap_i64` instruction, which is defined as

> Return i modulo  2^N .

(with N = 32) and should convert a 64 bit integer to a 32 bit one (See [op-wrap](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/exec/numerics.html#op-wrap)).

Unfortunately, I'm having a problem understanding this. I could of course just write

```java
return (int) (i % (1 << 32))
```

but IntelliJ already hints that this entire expression can be replaced by 0 and this is also the result if I execute it.

Surely, this is not what the instruction should be about, but what should it be? 2^32 is such a large number, which makes not much sense here. I guess it should rather be something bit-wise, but what?

Comment: It is the lower 32 bits only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us consider this:

```
   return (int) (i % (1 << 32))
```

In `1 << 32` the left-hand operand is an **int**, so the right-hand operand is [reduced modulo 32](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19).  Thus it is effectively `1 << 0`, which is 1.

So we now have `i % 1`, or the remainder when `i` is divided by 1, which is zero for all values of `i`.

You could salvage this by writing

```
   return (int) (i % (1L << 32))
```

but I find it clearer to write

```
   return (int) (i & 0xffffffffL)
```

since the remainder when dividing by 2-to-the-N is just the N low-order bits,
which for N=32 (size of an **int**) in Java [reduces to just the cast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)

```
   return (int)i;
```